# Weed tourism: alternatives to Amsterdam

Tags: netherlands, amsterdam, drugs

I am looking for a city recommendation in the Netherlands to engage in weed tourism.

**Here's what I am looking for**

- **cozy** coffeeshops or bars where you can smoke weed.

this would be an optimal amount of coziness:
[image: this would be optimal]

- open atmosphere: normal to walk around totally stoned, like in Amsterdam
- park within 15 minutes walking distance to the city center or the "coffeeshop center of gravity", since most of them are usually located close to each other.

Comment: Hmm. As far as I remember, Amsterdam has fairly decent city center supermarkets.  Haarlem is 15 minutes away by train; why not just go and check it out yourself?

Comment: Are you looking only in Netherlands?

Comment: Is smoking weed in public places even allowed in the Netherlands? Can't one only smoke in the privacy of one's home and in coffee shops?

Comment: Downvoted because three out of your four cons are totally untrue.  [Vondelpark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vondelpark) is a giant park in central Amsterdam.  There are many supermarkets too.

Comment: I feel we should not answer (or even allow) this question. Weed is illegal in the Netherlands, even if officially ignored. (Besides, very little research will show you that the rules for Amsterdam go for most of the country, no research done by OP.)

Comment: I hope the site doesn't officially approve of questions requesting assistance in illegal activities.  But then again, it's not illegal to look for another location... otherwise, maybe the question should be deleted (or re-written).

Comment: First time using this board. Wow, you guys are professionals, love it. I am looking just in the Netherlands. Vondelpark is great, but it is too far away from the very center. Most touristy things are between the Central station and Spui. I did no research on supermarkets, I just didnt encounter one. I will rewrite the question.

Comment: @odin1337 This is Amsterdam, you're not supposed to walk ;-). Vondelpark is 9 minutes from Dam or 2 minutes from Rĳksmuseum, by bicycle of course ;-).

Comment: Unlike what the question says, it is not common, accepted or legal to walk around Amsterdam completely stoned.

Answer (score 9):

Have you considered the US state of Colorado?

Supposedly, there are more marijuana "dispensaries" (as they are known from the days when the state was still trying to maintain the "medical marijuana" figleaf) in Colorado than there are McDonalds and Starbucks put together.  There are also beautiful mountains and some of the best hiking, camping, and skiing in the world, plus dozens of cute quirky little mountain towns like Aspen, Vale, Boulder, and Steamboat Springs. The western part is a vast and thorny desert.

The downside is all the large cities are in the east, and they have that same dusty, wind-scoured, dull feeling of a lot of Great Plains cities.  But if you stay up in the mountains, you'll be fine.

Comment: @ZachLipton I think OP only added the sentence about Netherlands after this answer was posted. I came here to suggest Uruguay and only saw the mention of Netherlands now ;)

Comment: @Kuba Ah yes, apologies. Constraints added after you've answered are always irritating.